# How can i change cart summary during checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, cart, order-summary

How can i change the cart summary in magento 2 checkout.

When i enter to checkout in shipping section i see this.
[image]

and when i reach on payment method i can see this.
[image]

How can i make shipping section same as payment section.

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

@avesh, first need to understand **why Magento does not show Cart total/subtotal and order total/grand total at Shipping steps**.

Magento **has optimized the checkout at this version** and using l**ocal storage for saving checkout data** like Cart item items, shipping address, shipping address at local storage and it save it Magento database when place an order.

If you will check magento2 checkout process then you can see that Magento **does not calculate  shipping rates** until s**hipping address selected or create the new address** and also this s**hipping address does not save at database as the shipping address until the order placed** and data is  saved at **local storage**.

After selecting or creating shipping address Magento calls the shipping estimate API ,which only need address fields values like `country, region id, region, city and postcode` **from local storage to fetch shipping method list for current cart**.

**In this way, Magento optimized the checkout process that why Magento does not show select shipping rate at checkout shipping step, So it is not relevant to show it.**
If you will default luma theme then you understand  **shipping price is showing as `Not yet calculated`.
[image]

Hope, you have understand my point.

Comment: Ya. but in my case it should display.

Comment: If shipping is not selected is should show yet to calculate.

Comment: Why you thought it should show?.May magento  checkout summary bar knockout js and html  template files in override by another moduke